# How do i find inline CSS styles within HTML body tags?

Tags: javascript, css, styles, inline

I'm helping out with some CSS work and it seems that some of the CSS has been added inline by some developers. We don't want any inline CSS, so I was wondering if there was a way of detecting whether or not there was any inline CSS in the `<body>` using JavaScript?

If this is possible, my plan was to create an analytics tag to record pages that have inline styles.

I've tried to find an answer to this but all of the responses i've found have been for finding a specific style or element style, my problem being that I don't know what styles have been used on which elements or where (and we have 1,000 pages so i'd rather not go through each page manually.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what, precisely, you mean by *inline* either or both of:

```
if (document.querySelector("[style]")) { ... }      // For style attributes
if (document.querySelector("style")) { ... }        // For style elements
```

… will tell you if there are any matches.

Unfortunately, they will also catch styles added with JavaScript (even if it something like `jQuery(some_selector).show();`).

You'd need to look at the raw source code to avoid catching those, and that is probably done by writing a bot (with no browser involvement) to run a similar test on each page.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin - that does seem to work but unfortunately our tag manager snippet includes a style tag in the <body>! Will have to see if I can work around it. When you say bot, do you mean something like a python scraper?

Comment: "When you say bot, do you mean something like a python scraper?" — The programming language is irrelevant. You need something that parses the HTML without executing the JavaScript and is capable of finding all your URLs.